# D3 - Make children fill parent group

Tags: javascript, css, layout, d3.js, spacing

I am trying to make a simple rectangular structure for single-nested data in D3.  I would like the result to look like the following image:

[image: The desired menu structure]

In other words, each group's items should be sized so that all groups take up the same space.

The [JSFiddle that I have made](http://jsfiddle.net/bradmarxmoosepi/p4duswb5/12/) does not yield the correct result:

```
var item_groups_enter = item_groups.enter()
    .append("g")
    .classed("item-group", true)
    .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
    return ("translate(0, " + 50 * i + ")"); // !!! THIS NEEDS TO CHANGE !!!
});

// Append a rectangle for each item
item_groups_enter.append("rect")
    .attr("width", main_group_width)
    .attr("height", 50) // !!! THIS NEEDS TO CHANGE !!!
.attr("fill", function (d, i) {
    return colours(i)
});

// Also append a label for each item
item_groups_enter.append("text")
    .text(function (d) {
    return (d)
})
    .attr("x", main_group_width * 0.5)
    .attr("y", 25) // !!! THIS NEEDS TO CHANGE !!!
.style("text-anchor", "middle");
```

I realise that I would somehow need to need to pass the `main-group`s' data (specifically, the number of children) to the `item_group`s, but I am unsure how to do this.  I did try setting a custom attribute `childCount` on the `main_group`, but the code became quite messy referencing parent nodes (and then grandparent nodes later on).

What would be the way to do this?  I am unsure if I should even be thinking about the solution in terms of D3, or in terms of CSS?

Comment: why are you not using treemap layout http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582

Comment: Two main reasons:

Firstly, the treemap may not  arrange items in the exact order required, as it looks like it uses a layout algorithm based on item 'value', which is not important in this application. 

Secondly, I want to learn how to implement this from the ground-up as the skills can be used in further visualisations.

Comment: @BradleyMarques It sounds like you only need to divide the total size by the number of items to get height/width.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Lars.  I realise that that is what needs to happen.  The problem is that I cannot seem to be able to pass the parents' nodes data into the children.  I will update the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a function with [`selection.attr`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#attr),  `this` is set  to the current DOM element. You can use it to access the parent selection and through it the underlying data :

For example,

```
var item_groups_enter = item_groups.enter()
    .append("g")
    .classed("item-group", true)
    .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
        // this is the g node
        var parentdatum = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum();
        var itemY = available_height/parentdatum.values.length * i;

        return ("translate(0, " + itemY + ")");
    });
```

```js
    var data = [{
        group: "Fruits",
        values: ["Apple", "Banana", "Pear", "Plum"]
    }, {
        group: "Cakes",
        values: ["Chocolate Cake", "Red Velvet Cake", "Carrot Cake"]
    }, {
        group: "Dogs",
        values: ["Spaniel", "Chow", "Dachshund", "Bulldog", "Beagle", "Boxer", "Pug"]
    }]

    // Get a handle on the svg HTML element
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 500)
        .attr("height", 500)

    // Calculate spacing
    var available_width = parseInt(svg.style("width"));
    var available_height = parseInt(svg.style("height"));
    var main_group_width = available_width / data.length;

    // Define the colours to use
    var colours = d3.scale.category10();

    // Make an HTML group for each of the groups in the data
    var main_groups = svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(data);

    // For each datum entered, append a new HTML group
    main_groups.enter()
        .append("g")
        .classed("main-group", true)
        .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
        return ("translate(" + i * main_group_width + ", 0)");
    })

    // Append a new group, an "item group" for each of the values in each of the main groups
    var item_groups = main_groups.selectAll("g")
        .data(function (d) {
        return (d.values)
    });

    var item_groups_enter = item_groups.enter()
        .append("g")
        .classed("item-group", true)
        .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
            var parentdatum = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum();
        return ("translate(0, " + available_height/parentdatum.values.length * i + ")");
    });

    // Append a rectangle for each item
    item_groups_enter.append("rect")
        .attr("width", main_group_width)
        .attr("height", function() {
            // we want the grand parent node
         var parentdatum = d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode).datum();
      return available_height/parentdatum.values.length;
     }) 
        .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
            return colours(i)
        });

    // Also append a label for each item
    item_groups_enter.append("text")
        .text(function (d) {
            return (d)
        })
        .attr("x", main_group_width * 0.5)
        .attr("y", 25)
        .style("text-anchor", "middle");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

---

You could could also traverse the groups defined by the `item_groups` selection (one group per parent element in `main_groups.selectAll("g")`) and assign your properties. For example

```
item_groups_enter.forEach(function(g, i) {
    var parentdatum = d3.select(g.parentNode).datum();
    var h = available_height/parentdatum.values.length;
    var selection = d3.selectAll(g);

   selection.attr("transform", function (d, i) {
       return ("translate(0, " + h * i + ")");
   });

   selection.select('rect')
        .attr("height", h);

   selection.select('text')
        .attr("y", h/2);
});
```

You can use the `parentNode` defined on each group to determine the correct parent data.

```js
var data = [{
    group: "Fruits",
    values: ["Apple", "Banana", "Pear", "Plum"]
}, {
    group: "Cakes",
    values: ["Chocolate Cake", "Red Velvet Cake", "Carrot Cake"]
}, {
    group: "Dogs",
    values: ["Spaniel", "Chow", "Dachshund", "Bulldog", "Beagle", "Boxer", "Pug"]
}]

// Get a handle on the svg HTML element
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500)

// Calculate spacing
var available_width = parseInt(svg.style("width"));
var available_height = parseInt(svg.style("height"));
var main_group_width = available_width / data.length;

// Define the colours to use
var colours = d3.scale.category10();

// Make an HTML group for each of the groups in the data
var main_groups = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(data);

// For each datum entered, append a new HTML group
main_groups.enter()
    .append("g")
    .classed("main-group", true)
    .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
    return ("translate(" + i * main_group_width + ", 0)");
})

// Append a new group, an "item group" for each of the values in each of the main groups
var item_groups = main_groups.selectAll("g")
    .data(function (d) {
        return (d.values)
    });

var item_groups_enter = item_groups.enter()
    .append("g")
    .classed("item-group", true);


item_groups_enter.append("rect")
    .attr("width", main_group_width)
    .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
        return colours(i)
    });

item_groups_enter.append("text")
    .text(function (d) {
     return (d)
 })
    .attr("x", main_group_width * 0.5)
    .attr("y", 25)
 .style("text-anchor", "middle");


item_groups_enter.forEach(function(g, i) {
    var parentdatum = d3.select(g.parentNode).datum();
 var h = available_height/parentdatum.values.length;
    var selection = d3.selectAll(g);
    
   selection.attr("transform", function (d, i) {
       return ("translate(0, " + h * i + ")");
   });
    
   selection.select('rect')
  .attr("height", h);
    
   selection.select('text')
  .attr("y", h/2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer.  Is this an good way of doing it?  Accessing the parent, then the grandparent seems a bit messy to me.  But this does indeed produce the required result.

Comment: I might be wrong, but as far as I understand http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/#data , relations between selections are not preserved and so you have to use the DOM nodes to climb up the chain and `parentNode` is the easiest way to do that

Comment: @BradleyMarques I added an alternative solution, maybe a bit cleaner in its `parentNode` usage.